# Last foreach item when using a generator

Tags: php, foreach, generator

Usually, before entering a `foreach` loop, we would call `reset` or `end` to find the first or last item in an array. But, this doesn't play well with generators, especially those which are memory intensive. The simple solution would be to use `iterator_to_array`. Again, not the ideal solution. It requires copying the whole output to memory and a second iteration.

Checking for the first item could be done by setting a simple `bool` before the loop. But what about the last item? With access to the class which supplies the generator, I can implement the `\Countable` interface to get the number of expected iterations. That only works IF I have access, sometimes it may be third party and cannot be modified.

How can I detect the last iteration of a generator loop without having to loop through beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `while` loop you can manually check a generator state by the additional call of `valid()` method:

```
function g() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

$g = g();

while ($g->valid()) {
    echo "Value ", $g->current();
    $g->next();
    echo $g->valid() ? " is not last\n" : " is last\n";
}
```